# API returning several string escapes

Tags: javascript, json, string, api, return

I'm having some trouble with an API that is returning a responseBody with several string escapes, which makes it impossible to use JSON.parse on it. I have alrealdy been able to treat it and somehow make it a little better to read it, but is still not possible to use JSON.parse or some other function. I need to treat this in a way that I can read it as a JSON.

**This is my responseBody:**
`{"options":{"host":"10.251.28.20","port":"10002","path":"/ScadaHistJson/GetData","method":"POST","headers":{"Content-Type":"application/json","Content-Length":128}},"responseBody":"{\"json\":\"[[\\\"0201013667\\\",\\\"035ET228327\\\",\\\"6707036-1\\\",201,10,\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570724413000)\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570725591000)\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"R BELA VISTA,794,CS 05 CEP-09843120 Bairro:JARDIM DA REPRESA Cidade:SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO\\/SP\\\",\\\"035ET228327\\\",null,\\\"N\\\",19.63,\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570724413000)\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570726844000)\\\\\\/\\\",null,\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570724413000)\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570724413000)\\\\\\/\\\",null,\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570724580000)\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570724580000)\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570724640000)\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570724640000)\\\\\\/\\\",\\\"\\\\\\/Date(1570725591000)\\\\\\/\\\",0,\\\"AM003\\\",8.83]]\",\"message\":\"SUCCESS\",\"status\":0}"}`

I used JSON.stringify(eval("(" + INSIGHT.responseBody + ")")) and the result was the following:

`"{\"json\":\"[[\"0201013667\",\"035ET228327\",\"6707036-1\",201,10,\"/Date(1570724413000)/\",\"/Date(1570725591000)/\",\"R BELA VISTA,794,CS 05 CEP-09843120 Bairro:JARDIM DA REPRESA Cidade:SAO BERNARDO DO CAMPO/SP\",\"035ET228327\",null,\"N\",19.63,\"/Date(1570724413000)/\",\"/Date(1570726844000)/\",null,\"/Date(1570724413000)/\",\"/Date(1570724413000)/\",null,\"/Date(1570724580000)/\",\"/Date(1570724580000)/\",\"/Date(1570724640000)/\",\"/Date(1570724640000)/\",\"/Date(1570725591000)/\",0,\"AM003\",8.83]]\",\"message\":\"SUCCESS\",\"status\":0}"`

Does anybody know how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the responseBody is a valid json (RFC 8259). I tested it using (https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

If you are having trouble getting the content from the "json" array property, what I tried was to double parse the responseBody in the following way:

```
  const response = JSON.parse(INSIGHT.responseBody);
  const values = JSON.parse(response.json);
```